# Create a list or array of date time using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a list of date time in python using `pandas`. I want something like:

```
2023-05-10_00:00:00
2023-05-10_01:00:00
2023-05-10_02:00:00
.....
.....
2023-05-10_23:00:00
```

So basically I want data with datetime with 1 hour increment. I tried the following

```
dt = pd.to_datetime('2023-05-10',format='%Y-%m-%d')
print(dt)
```

which gives me the following, and it is not exactly what I am looking for

```
2023-05-10 00:00:00
```

I was also thinking of creating a list or array with just the date `2023-05-10` and another array with only time with 1-hr increment, and then paste them together with a separator `_`. I am not sure how to do this in Python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)?

Comment: I tried it, that didnt work

Comment: And you tried `freq="H"`?

Comment: No, I haven't, let me try.

Comment: `pd.date_range('2023-05-10', '2023-05-11', freq='H').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i make 3 data for example

```
pd.date_range('2023-05-10', periods=3, freq='H').strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
```

output:

```
Index(['2023-05-10_00:00:00', '2023-05-10_01:00:00', '2023-05-10_02:00:00'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.date_range('2023-05-01', '2023-05-02', freq='H')

DatetimeIndex(['2023-05-01 00:00:00', '2023-05-01 01:00:00',
               '2023-05-01 02:00:00', '2023-05-01 03:00:00',
               '2023-05-01 04:00:00', '2023-05-01 05:00:00',
               '2023-05-01 06:00:00', '2023-05-01 07:00:00',
               '2023-05-01 08:00:00', '2023-05-01 09:00:00',
               '2023-05-01 10:00:00', '2023-05-01 11:00:00',
               '2023-05-01 12:00:00', '2023-05-01 13:00:00',
               '2023-05-01 14:00:00', '2023-05-01 15:00:00',
               '2023-05-01 16:00:00', '2023-05-01 17:00:00',
               '2023-05-01 18:00:00', '2023-05-01 19:00:00',
               '2023-05-01 20:00:00', '2023-05-01 21:00:00',
               '2023-05-01 22:00:00', '2023-05-01 23:00:00',
               '2023-05-02 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
```